# “Asked” Vs. “Having asked” vs. “having been asked”

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> 1) **asked** about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up...
>
> 2) **Having asked** about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up...
>
> 3) **Having been asked** about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up...

What is the difference in meaning among  these three sentences; are all of them  conveying the same thing ?

Are they all grammatically and semantically acceptable and correct?

And in the first sentence, is “asked” finite or non-finite verb?

Comment: 1 and 3 are roughly equivalent.  2 isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your example 1 is a reduced subordinate clause.  The full form would be "When she was asked about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up..."  Accordingly, "asked" is part of a passive construction and is the past participle of "ask".  (Personally, I'd prefer to call it a "passive participle".)

Similar to the "whiz" reduction of relative clauses, "she" referring to the main clause subject and the form of "be" can be deleted, giving "When asked about her parents, Ms. Angelina ..."  Additionally, "when" can be left understood (as other subordinate conjunctions can be, sometimes).

The other two examples are only marginally acceptable, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Well, I used “asking” instead of “asked”, would it be she same as you me had mentioned that “when she was asking....?

Comment: Yes. ----------

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that they have the same meaning. "Asked" and "Having been asked" seem to have the same meaning. A second party did the asking.

"Having asked about her parents, Ms. Angela..." would mean that Ms. Angela had done the asking.

Answer (score 0):

1) [having been] Asked about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up...

3) Having been asked about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up...

The square brackets shows how they are basically the same thing. Someone asked her about her parents. That's the meaning. The questions are directed at her. She is not asking the questions.

2) Having asked about her parents, Ms. Angelina said she was uncertain of their names and promised to look them up...

2) has a different meaning

In 2) Ms. Angelina is asking someone else about her own parents. She is asking the questions. It is an active sense. She asked about her parents. She asked the questions, the questions were not asked to or of her.